# How to pass the right context to docker-compose build?

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose

I have the following docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  repo_svc:
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile: ../build/Dockerfile
```

Running the command, I have got the following error message:

```
docker-compose -f ./deployments/docker-compose.yml build
Building repo_svc
unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: lstat /home/developer/versioner/services/build: no such file or directory
ERROR: Service 'repo_svc' failed to build : Build failed
```

The folder structure of GO project:

[image]

I would like to pass to `context: ../` the `repo-svc` folder context. However, I do not know why it is looking in the `/home/developer/versioner/services/build` folder. It even does not exist.

Comment: Does `dockerfile: build/Dockerfile` work?  The documentation isn't 100% clear on how relative paths in both `context:` and `dockerfile:` interact, but if `../build/...` is interpreted relative to the `..` context directory, it would step up one level out of the source tree entirely.

Comment: (It's pretty common to put both the `docker-compose.yml` file and the `Dockerfile` in the project root directory, and then you can just specify `build: .` without trying to figure out these paths.)

Answer (score 0):

I think the context should look like:

```
version: "3.9"

    services:
      repo_svc:
        build:
          context: ../build
          dockerfile: Dockerfile
```